# Strange MySQL SELECT execution times

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm having hard time figuring out why execution times of similar queries differ so much from each other. I have a simple `SELECT` query like this:

```
SELECT
    `location_id`,
    `datetime`,
    `year`,
    `month`,
    `load`
FROM  load_report_rows
WHERE location_id = '16583'
AND   load_report_id = '1'
AND   year = '2010'
```

This query runs merrily in 0.1837 seconds, but if I change the `location_id` to "18260", the query suddenly takes 2.7012 seconds. All three fields that are used in the `WHERE` clause are indexed and both queries return exactly 8760 rows. The `EXPLAIN` for this query returns the following info:

```
id               1
select_type      SIMPLE
table            load_report_rows
type             index_merge
possible_keys    load_report_id,location_id,year
key              location_id,load_report_id,year
key_len          4,4,4
ref              NULL
rows             3349
extra            using intersect(location_id,load_report_id,year); using where
```

MySQL query profiler gives the following for each query:

```
+--------------------------------+----------+----------+
| Status                         | Query 1  | Query 2  |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000023 | 0.000023 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000072 | 0.000068 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000010 | 0.000068 |
| opening tables                 | 0.000012 | 0.000012 |
| system lock                    | 0.000005 | 0.000004 |
| table lock                     | 0.000008 | 0.000008 |
| init                           | 0.000050 | 0.000026 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000030 | 0.000014 |
| statistics                     | 0.000461 | 0.001048 |
| preparing                      | 0.000022 | 0.000043 |
| executing                      | 0.000003 | 0.000004 |
| sending data                   | 0.100939 | 2.649942 |
| end                            | 0.000013 | 0.000040 |
| end                            | 0.000004 | 0.000004 |
| query end                      | 0.000004 | 0.000004 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000012 | 0.000013 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000008 | 0.000008 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000002 | 0.000003 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000006 | 0.000005 |
+--------------------------------+----------+----------+
```

The `sending data` stage takes significantly longer with the second query. What steps are included in that? Here's the table structure for the relevant fields if that helps:

```
`id`              int(11)
`load_report_id`  int(11)
`location_id`     int(11)
`datetime`        datetime
`year`            int(4)
`month`           int(2)
`load`            decimal(16,8)

PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
KEY `load_report_id` (`load_report_id`)
KEY `location_id` (`location_id`)
KEY `year` (`year`)
KEY `month` (`month`)
```

Any ideas what could cause the second query run so slowly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of suggestions.

First, I would add a multi-column index to cover those 3 columns. This way you can scan a single index rather than doing an index merge:

```
ALTER TABLE load_report_rows
  ADD KEY location_report_year_idx (location_id,load_report_id,year);
```

The new index makes the location_id index somewhat redundant, so you may want to consider dropping it as well.

Secondly, I would recommend rewriting the query to input the ints as ints, not strings. This will avoid an unnecessary implicit type conversion which may lead to slower performance. It's probably not the cause of your specific problem, but I think it's a good practice in general:

```
SELECT
    `location_id`,
    `datetime`,
    `year`,
    `month`,
    `load`
FROM  load_report_rows
WHERE location_id = 16583
AND   load_report_id = 1
AND   year = 2010
```

Comment: This did the trick, my total running time dropped from 5 minutes to 44 seconds. Dropping the quotes doesn't seem to make any difference. I guess when MySQL optimizes the query before executing it, the strings are automatically converted to ints before processing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`sending data` is a misleading description. It actually includes *both* the time spent executing the query *and* the time spent sending the result over the wire. [source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638624/mysql-profiler-sending-data) [source 2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/general-thread-states.html) [source 3](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,241461,242012#msg-242012)

Since both queries generate approximately the same amount of data, the difference must be in the execution stage. There are a few possibilities:

- Maybe the three indexes don't generate a useful intersection in the right order when `location_id` is 18260. Try adding a multi-column index as @Ike Walker suggested.
- Maybe the rows to be returned in the second query are fragmented all over the disk. This would make MySQL spend a considerable amount of time just waiting for the disk to seek to the next location. Try [optimizing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html) your table. Fragmentation can also happen with heavily used indexes, so also try dropping and recreating some indexes.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be caching. You are causing MySQL to caste/convert your values (strings/numbers). All the fields you are searching on are int, but you are passing mysql a string to search on. Remove the quotes from around the numbers you are searching on and see what happens.

MySQL may be converting all the values in the table to strings in order to compare, rather than converting the search string to a number. You only posted 1 explain query, you should post both to see if the execution paths are different.

Answer (score 0):

The `sending data` state refers to when MySQL is actually sending data over the wire.  So the slowness could very well be because id 18260 simply returns many more rows than your first query.

Comment: I've updated my question, both queries return exactly 8760 rows so that cannot be the problem.