# MySQL slow query with 2 inner joins

Tags: mysql, indexing, left-join, query-performance

The following query takes 4 seconds to run and I don't know why since the index results are low. The way it works can't be changed (since it's a compatibility query to get the appName from 2 different systems)

Do you have any ideas?

```sql
SELECT runList.appName
FROM projectList
INNER JOIN varMeta ON (projectList.id = varMeta.projectId)
INNER JOIN runList ON (projectList.projectName = runList.appName)
WHERE varMeta.htmlvar_content = "example-app-name"
ORDER BY runList.id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys      | key         | key_len | ref                       | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | runList     | index | env,appName,all    | PRIMARY     | 8       | NULL                      |    3 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | projectList | ref   | PRIMARY,appNameIDX | appNameIDX  | 138     | compat.runList.appName    |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | varMeta     | ref   | varMetaIDX         | varMetaIDX  | 5       | compat.projectList.id     |   63 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+------+-------------+
```

This is the profile for that query :

```
+--------------------+----------+
| Status             | Duration |
+--------------------+----------+
| starting           | 0.000215 |
| Opening tables     | 0.000043 |
| System lock        | 0.000034 |
| Table lock         | 0.000015 |
| init               | 0.000081 |
| optimizing         | 0.000029 |
| statistics         | 0.000345 |
| preparing          | 0.000033 |
| executing          | 0.000009 |
| Sorting result     | 0.000009 |
| Sending data       | 3.023702 |
| end                | 0.000018 |
| query end          | 0.000004 |
| freeing items      | 0.000223 |
| logging slow query | 0.000004 |
| cleaning up        | 0.000005 |
+--------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Do you have an index on varMeta.htmlvar_content? Can you try creating one?

Comment: Linked for info (not dupe): [Explanation of Sending data in Query Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638624/mysql-profiler-sending-data)

Comment: Do you have indexes on `projectList.projectName`, `runList.appName`, `runList.id`, `varMeta.htmlvar_content`, `projectList.id`, `varMeta.projectId` ?

Comment: yes, all those index currently exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to take a guess here, because you haven't told us what fields or indexes you have, nor have you mentioned the number of rows in each table. (So this could be rubbish).

You need a particular single value of `varMeta.html_varcontent`, then you need to join with `varMeta.projectID`. So create a compound index `(html_varcontent, projectID)` on your `varMeta` table.  Why does this help? Because you want a certain value of the leftmost column in the index, and then MySQL needs to retrieve all the possible values of the other column. MySQL can random access and then scan through the index for that data, without having to use the table data. It's faster.

Similarly,  you are doing the `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` thing on your `runList` table. To make that work efficiently try creating the compound index `(appName, id)` on your `runList` table. Your join operation looks up one or more values of `appName`, then has to look for the numerically highest `id` number. This is fast to do in a compound index.

Finally, one of the following two compound indexes on your `projectList` table should help: `(id, appName)` or `(appName, id)`. Which one depends on how MySQL optimizes your query after the other indexes are available.

Comment: Which one of the last two I suggested, just out of curiosity?